# Printing abstracted objects c++

Tags: c++, class, pointers, polymorphism

**EDIT--** I fixed the original problem of only printing out memory addresses instead of the values thanks to you guys, but I'm still not getting the expected output.  Here is my new output:

```
Type: AA, Name: Energizer, Part Number: 123, Price: 29.99
 - 1
Type: Plain, Name: Rainx, Part Number: 9876, Price: 9.99
 - 1
Type: Round, Name: Firestone, Part Number: 5432, Price: 99.99
 - 1
Type: Tire, Name: Firewheel, Part Number: 6666, Price: 49.99
 - 1
Type: Wheel-Tire, Name: Best Wheel Tire Combo, Part Number: 2424, Price: 199.99
 - 1
Type: Frame, Name: A-Frame, Part Number: 777, Price: 30000
 - 1
Type: Engine, Name: Diesel, Part Number: 4444, Price: 8000
 - 1
```

Notice that each part is only printing 4 fields-- the default fields of the Auto_Part constructor.  My derived classes vary anywhere from 5-8 fields. I tried adding the keyword `virtual` to the `Inventory::add_part()` function, but I got a Segmentation Fault: 11 error. How do I fix this?

I have an inventory of auto parts. **I want to print out the entire inventory, however my print function is printing the memory addresses instead of the values**.

I have an `Auto_Part` class that is my base class, and several different derived classes (Battery, Frame, Engine, etc.). I passed in each part to the `Inventory::add_part` function using the following code:

```
nventory inventory;
Battery *bat = new Battery("AA", "Energizer", 123, 29.99, 2, 4, 9, 60);

Windshield_Wiper *ww = new Windshield_Wiper("Plain", "Rainx", 9876, 9.99, 24, "Skinny");

Wheel *wheel = new Wheel("Round", "Firestone", 5432, 99.99, "drag", "black", 24, 9, "Crossed");

Tire *tire = new Tire("Tire", "Firewheel", 6666, 49.99, "Drag_Racing", 32, 3, 16, "Great speed", "Loaded");

Wheel_Tire_Combo *wtc = new Wheel_Tire_Combo("Wheel-Tire", "Best Wheel Tire Combo", 2424, 199.99, "Drag Racing", 32, 3, 16, "Slow Speed", "Unloaded?", "Drag" , "black",25, 8, "Bolted");

Frame * frame = new Frame("Frame", "A-Frame", 777, 30000.00, "Solid Frame");

Engine * engine = new Engine("Engine", "Diesel", 4444, 8000.00, 8, "e85");

vector<Auto_Part*> parts;
parts.push_back(bat);
parts.push_back(ww);
parts.push_back(wheel);
parts.push_back(tire);
parts.push_back(wtc);
parts.push_back(frame);
parts.push_back(engine);

for (Auto_Part* ap : parts){
    inventory.add_part(ap);
}

cout << inventory;
```

Here is my add_part function:

```
void Inventory::add_part(Auto_Part* part)
{
    if(inventory.count(part) == 0)
        inventory.insert(std::pair<Auto_Part*, int>(part, 1));
    else
        inventory.at(part) += 1;
}
```

And here is my << overload for printing:

```
   std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& ost, const Inventory& inv)
{
    for(auto x : inv.inventory)
    {
        ost << x.first << " - " << x.second << std::endl;
    }
    return ost;
}
```

Yet, when I print, I get the memory addresses instead of the values:

```
0x7fcce1402690 - 1
0x7fcce14026f0 - 1
0x7fcce14027e8 - 1
0x7fcce1402890 - 1
0x7fcce1402998 - 1
0x7fcce14029e0 - 1
0x7fcce1402a40 - 1
```

I'm not sure where my error is, though I believe it's probably due to me not dereferencing somewhere.

Comment: That's because the `first` element is a pointer (`Auto_Part*`). You can probably figure out what you need to dereference.

Comment: Instead of the edit, it would have been more appropriate to ask a new question. Any answers given so far address only the first problem, whereas new answers likely only will address the second one. As you can only accept one single answer, which one would you accept?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know. I will create a new question. What's the etiquette of accepting an answer? The first person that posted a solution? The most upvoted?

Comment: @user242424 Please accept the answer that was the most helpfull for you. Don't give a **** about what others vote for or the answerers typing speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @molbdnilo pointed out, you are storing a pointer and an int in each pair.

You just need to dereference the `first` of the pair before passing it to `operator<<`

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& ost, const Inventory& inv)
{
    for(auto x : inv.inventory)
    {
        ost << *(x.first) << " - " << x.second << std::endl;
    }
    return ost;
}
```

Comment: Okay, so it printed, but it only printed the default constructor of the auto_part class and not the unique fields of each derived class. I tried adding the virtual keyword to the inventory::add_part() function but then I got a segmentation fault. Any ideas? I'll edit the original post to show new output and expected output.

Comment: @user242424 You'd need a virtual `operator<<` within your auto part class. Unfortunately, having such one would force you to do `part << stream`; obviously not what you want... Way around: have a virtual function being called from operator<< that does the printing (receiving the stream as parameter)  - and can be overridden in derived classes.

Answer (score 1):

The `first` element of your `pair` is a pointer element. So when you pass it to the `<<` operator, it prints the memory address.

The simplest solution would be to change the

```
ost << x.first << // more code
```

in your overloaded operator with

```
ost << *x.first << // more code
```

Otherwise, you have to revise your entire data structure to directly hold the objects and not the pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Since `inventory.insert(std::pair<Auto_Part*, int>(part, 1));`

-> `x.first` is typed of `Auto_Part*` -> you need to `dereference` it first:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& ost, const Inventory& inv)
{
    for(auto& x : inv.inventory)
    {
        ost << *(x.first) << " - " << x.second << std::endl;
    }
    return ost;
}
```

Note: I use `auto& x` instead of `auto x`.